# Image Field required when updating/Editing a table with EF and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

I have abit of a confusing issue here. I am creating a blog in mvc. `Users` of the blog can `Post` a Blog. However I have recently changed the Post table in Enitity Framework to include the ability to upload a `Picture (varbinary(max))`.

I have handled this in the User `Create` Post controller action and I can successfully upload and display pictures on users `Posts`.

However my problem comes when an Administrator has to allow the publishing of a post `(Simple Controller Scaffolding for Edit)`. (No user can post without approval) For this I have a field in my `Post` table called `Published (bit, not null)`.

When I try to edit a post of a user to publish it with my AdminController, I get the error when I save changes:

> MyBlogger.Models.Post: The Picture field is required.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Post post)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

The problem is difficult to work out because in my Edit View I cant just say `@Html.Picture(m => m.Picture)` in order to display a picture, I have to convert the Byte to Base64 and to display it I have to do this:

```
src="@Html.Raw("data:image/jpeg;base64," + ViewBag.ImageToShow)"
```

I dont have the option either in my Edit Action to do `db.AddOrUpdate(post);` I only have `db.SaveChanges();`

All im simply doing with my Edit Action is

> Find the post with the specified Id, Update the publish field of that
>   specific post, Save the changes to the db.

Im not sure why its grumbling saying that the picture field is required? Its either because the table entry for the `Picture` field is set to `Not Null` or because its saving all table entries for Post again, this presents the problem of simply adding/updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post back your modified model `post` model binder cannot bind your image to `Picture` property again. If you want to modify some of your entity's properties, you can simply fetch it and modify desired properties and save again.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Post post)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Post oldPost = db.Posts.Find(post.id);
            oldPost.Published=post.Published;
            // repeat for others. 
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
       //
    }
}
```

But if you want to modify `Picture` property also you must use `HttpPostedFileBase` class to get new image and save it like above.

Comment: You already added picture to your model in `Create` action. Therefor when you fetch it again in `edit` action your entity already contain picture.